# Tooltip of JointJS Stencil

Tags: jointjs

Can anyone please help me understand how to add tooltip to the stencil shapes.

I can't find a way how to achieve this. I would love to give dynamic text if it allows.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I still have not got any reply on this. Hence I am assuming there is no way to provide a dynamic text.

Answer (score 1):

You can define the tooltip when you define the shape through the `'.'` reference, example:

```
joint.shapes.devs.Model.define('app.MyShape', {
    attrs: {
      '.': {
        'data-tooltip': 'My Shape',
        'data-tooltip-position': 'bottom',
        'data-tooltip-position-selector': '.joint-stencil'
      },
    // other properties ...
    }
}
```